# TypeError in Pycharm (Python)

Tags: python

```py
if "show" | "display" in user_action:
    with open("../files/todos.txt", "r") as file:
        todos = file.readlines()
```

I want to run the code such that if user input is "show" or "display" then the code line will run.

Error shown:

```
if "show" | "display" in user_action: 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: `|` operator is not used to check multiple condition. Instead use `or` logical operator to  check multiple condition

Answer (score 1):

Replace
`if "show" | "display" in user_action:` to `if "show" in user_action or "display" in user_action:`